# Classification using KNN model in R

Tags: r, knn

I have two data frames and I want to use KNN model in these two dataframes. Data_frame_1 is my test data set and Data_frame_2 is my training data set. My target column is ECM category of Data_frame_2.
I want to classify Data_frame_1 according to Data_frame_2.
I want to compare measure_NY of Data_frame_1 with Measure column of Data_frame_2 and want output ECM category as new column in Data_frame_1.For example in Data_frame_1 column mesure_NY if column contain Air and Air Compressor or Air conditioner and LED or fixtures then I want HVAC Equipment and Lighting fixtures respectively in new ECM category column in Data_frame_1. Same I want for sub category. I am confused how can I able to do that using KNN model.

Data_frame_1

| measure_NY | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| Air Compressor | 2 |
| Air Compressor Hp | 3 |
| Air Compressor SHp | 4 |
| Air Compressor PHP1 | 5 |
| Air Compressor Replacement | 4 |
| Air Conditioner Central Unit Replacement | 7 |
| Boiler (Hot Water, Cast Iron) | 5 |
| Chiller Air Cooled With Condenser, Electrically Operated | 4 |

Data_frame_2

| ECM Category | Measure | Sub-Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lighting Fixtures | ENERGY STAR Downlights Fixture with Screw-In or Pin-Based Lamp, replacing Incandescent Fixture >60W | Flourocent Delamping |
| Lighting Fixtures | ENERGY STAR Downlights Fixture with Screw-In or Pin-Based Lamps, replacing CFL Fixture >32W | Flourocent Delamping |
| Lighting Fixtures | LED High-Bay Retrofit Kits, >20,000 LED lumens | Interior LED Lights |
| Lighting Fixtures | LED Accent/Track Lighting Fixtures | Interior LED Lights |
| HVAC Equipment | Air Cooled Air Conditioner < 5.4 tons | Chiller Equipment |
| HVAC Equipment | Packaged Terminal AC or PTHP 12.0 EER | Chiller Equipment |
| HVAC Equipment | VFD on HVAC Fan <=10 HP | Motors & Drives |
| HVAC Equipment | VFD on Heating Hot Water Pumps 21–30 H | Motors & Drives |

I ran this code

```
training_data_set_subset<-training_data_set[1:1097,1:2]
dim(training_data_set_subset)
sum(is.na(training_data_set_subset$`ECM Category`))
training_data_set_subset<-replace(training_data_set_subset,is.na(training_data_set_subset),"No data")
training_data_set_subset.n<-training_data_set_subset['Measure']
training_data_set_subset.n<-training_data_set_subset<-replace(training_data_set_subset.n,is.na(training_data_set_subset.n),"No data")
#Data Splicing: Data splicing basically involves splitting the data set into training and testing data set.
measure_NY_1<-measure_NY[,1]
train_data<-training_data_set_subset.n[1:1097,]
test_data<-measure_NY_1[1:655,]

dim(train_data)
dim(test_data)
#Creating seperate dataframe for 'ECM Category' feature which is our target.
train_data_labels<-training_data_set_subset[1:1097,1]

dim(train_data_labels)
# building knn model
#Install class package
install.packages('class')
# Load class package
library(class)

#Find the number of observation
nrow(train_data_labels)
sum(is.na(training_data_set_subset.n))
# root 0f 1097
#33.12

#k=33
k.33<-knn(train=train_data,test=test_data,cl=train_data_labels$ECM.Category,k=33)
```

but I get an error
Error in knn(train = train_scale, test = test_scale, cl, k = 22) :
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn(train = train_scale, test = test_scale, cl, k = 22) :
NAs introduced by coercion
2: In knn(train = train_scale, test = test_scale, cl, k = 22) :
NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: You can use the ```RTextTools``` package to do a text classification problem. However, I'm not sure whether KNN is included in the supported models

Comment: @Matthew Farant can you take look in my code once, Please